# I need help with making the lines sharper in a drawing

Tags: stroke, line-art

As the title says, I need help with making the lines sharper in a drawing my friend drew. He asked me if I can make the lines better, and I have tried going over it with the brush tool but it's going to take a long time. I was wondering if there might be a quicker way of doing this?
[image]

Thanks
Jake

Comment: What software do you have access to?

Comment: Define "sharp"? Those lines look fairly sharp already (in that the edges aren't fuzzy).

Comment: Traditionally, an illustrator would put another piece of vellum over that art and trace/redraw it in a more refined state. *Then* scan for digital use.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

As already mentioned above, you can always live trace and go from there.
If you don't have Adobe Illustrator, [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) is an opensource alternative.

Those lines look pretty sharp though so I get the impression that you either want to tidy the sketch up a little or make a workable digital version.

To tidy it  up a little;

Rather than colouring in all of the lines and sections with the brush tool, you can use either Photoshop or the opensource image editor [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) to mess with the [levels](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/levels.htm), jack up the [brightness and the contrast](http://www.bairarteditions.com/pages/tutorials/photoshop/excontrast.html) and then go from there.

You'd end up with something like this as a starting step;
[image]

Some more steps are mentioned [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/what-should-i-do-when-scanning-hand-drawn-images/1302#1302) about cleaning up hand drawn sketches as well as a wealth of online resources :)

Now if you want to make an illustration of your friends drawing questions like that have been [answered before](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26131/converting-drawing-to-vector-in-illustrator) and there are some tutorials online too.

Best of luck, hope I've helped.

Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1):

If it helps you can save this image trace (Illustrator, default tracing options) and continue editing in any editor you want:

[image]